# ¿Cómo hacer que se lean caracteres especiales? C++

Tags: c++

Recibo estas frases mediante un archivo en C++, pero no soy capaz de hacer que se vean los caracteres especiales en la consola. ¿Qué podría hacer para visualizarlos sin tener que utilizar ASCII en cada uno?

```
Johannes Thingnes Bø
Sjåstad Christiansen
Marte Olsbu Røiseland
```

Comment: En qué sistema operativo quieres lograr tu cometido? La consola de Linux no tiene dificultades para imprimir carácteres especiales. La de Windows si, ya que hay que cambiar la codificación a la que estás usando y tiene problemas para representar algunas.

Comment: Windows 10, 64 bits.

Comment: Usando setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "spanish" ) pude haber que se vieran las tildes y demás, pero todavía me faltan muchos caracteres especiales.

Answer (score 0):

`setlocale` es una función de C, también válida en C++.

Permite establecer cómo se imprimirá el texto en [varias categorías](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/LC_categories).

Probablemente esté afectando a algunos caracteres como indicas la categoría `LC_CTYPE`. Para cambiar todas la categorías puedes pasar `LC_ALL` como primer parámetro:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

Si el segundo parámetro es una cadena vacía `""`, se utiliza la configuración regional del usuario. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale

En C++, la forma que brinda [STL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) es:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
```

---

Si lo anterior no soluciona tu problema, puedes optar por usar la [API de Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/) aunque es más complicado:

```
// Cambias la codificación activa (UTF-16)
SetConsoleCP(1200);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1200);

// Lees el archivo
std::fstream file("utf16.txt", std::ios_base::in);

file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
int size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

std::string buffer;
buffer.reserve(size);

file.read(buffer.data(), size);
file.close();

auto out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
// Imprimes en consola
WriteConsoleW(out, buffer.c_str(), 57, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Una respuesta bastante completa sobre codificación de texto en C++: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17177904